# Linq.Expressions Value type implicit casting

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

How can I sort-of "up-cast" where if I have an expression `Expression.Constant(3)` and `Expression.Constant(3d)`, it will up-convert the int to a double?

I know I can convert using `Expression.Convert()` but what is the best way to determine which type can be implicitly up-cast?

I'm writing a simple equation evaluator, so the only expected input types are Value Types

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be *any* way of getting a list of all types that a given `Type` can be implicitly converted to at runtime.  You should probably re-design your program to avoid the situation in the first place, and not try to do this at runtime.

Comment: You just described the job of a compiler, which knows these things based on the C# language specifications.

Comment: Not any Type. Just Value Types

Comment: @TristanMcPherson That doesn't change the problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to consider here is that `System.Linq.Expressions`, which is used by both LINQ and the Dynamic Language Runtime, is designed to be a **language-agnostic** code model.  The idea is to make it possible to create a "compiler" that can transform expressions from any arbitrary language into LINQ/DLR trees.  Different languages have their own rules governing what kinds of conversions occur implicitly or explicitly, so the expression tree API and compiler tend to be very strict about requiring types to match up exactly.  It is the job of the "compiler writer" (or whatever code is generating these expression trees) to explicitly inject whichever conversions are required to match the source language semantics.

The semantics of your custom expression language are up to you; you can choose to base them off an existing language like C#, but you will not find many facilities within the LINQ/DLR frameworks to tell you which kinds of conversions "should" happen implicitly, because *there is no standard set of rules* for this; such rules are language-dependent.  Whatever rules you decide on, it will ultimately be up to you to inject the necessary conversions into your expression tree.  This is a non-trivial task, and there is no "one size fits all" solution that one can simply post to StackOverflow.

On the upside, there is very little cost to having "unnecessary" `Convert` expressions in your tree; if the bytecode-level conversion from one type to another is effectively a no-op, then no extra bytecode will be emitted when the expression is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

While browsing through the System.Linq.Expressions namespace in Reflector I found the following method that I used instead of a dynamic way.

```
    public static bool IsImplicitNumericConversion(Type source, Type destination)
    {
        TypeCode typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(source);
        TypeCode code2 = Type.GetTypeCode(destination);
        switch (typeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.Char:
                switch (code2)
                {
                    case TypeCode.UInt16:
                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                    case TypeCode.UInt32:
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                    case TypeCode.UInt64:
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            case TypeCode.SByte:
                switch (code2)
                {
                    case TypeCode.Int16:
                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        return true;
                }
                break;

            case TypeCode.Byte:
                switch (code2)
                {
                    case TypeCode.Int16:
                    case TypeCode.UInt16:
                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                    case TypeCode.UInt32:
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                    case TypeCode.UInt64:
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            case TypeCode.Int16:
                switch (code2)
                {
                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                switch (code2)
                {
                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                    case TypeCode.UInt32:
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                    case TypeCode.UInt64:
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            case TypeCode.Int32:
                switch (code2)
                {
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                switch (code2)
                {
                    case TypeCode.UInt32:
                    case TypeCode.UInt64:
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            case TypeCode.Int64:
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                switch (code2)
                {
                    case TypeCode.Single:
                    case TypeCode.Double:
                    case TypeCode.Decimal:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            case TypeCode.Single:
                return (code2 == TypeCode.Double);

            default:
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The method you refer to is used internally for a specific purpose, and you should not assume that you can forego an explicit `Convert` simply because this method tells you that two types are implicitly convertible.  It ultimately depends where and how the operands will be used.